# Перенос tarantoola с одного сервера на другой

Tags: база-данных, tarantool

День добрый, нужно все данные которые хранятся в **space** в БД tarantool перенести, в точно такой же **space**, на другой сервер. Перенос скриптов и других настроек не нужно, исключительно только данные..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый сервер должен быть запущен с возможностью сетевого подключения:

```lua
box.cfg{listen=<ip1:port>}
```

На втором сервере необходимо подключить репликацию к первому серверу:

```lua
box.cfg{replication={'<ip1:port>'}}
```

Подождать пока репликация подключится и скачает все данные всех спейсов.

И отключить репликацию, если в связи между серверами нет необходимости.

```lua
box.cfg{replication={}}
```